# Angularjs RadioButton

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have the following problem, when ng-value is a integer working and not working when ng-value is a string. Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

```
<input type="radio" name="grupoRadio" ng-value="1" ng-model="valor" > Certificado de cobertura sin nómina de personal
 <br>
<input type="radio" name="grupoRadio" ng-value='CNC' ng-model="valor" > Certificado de cobertura con nómina de personal completa
 <br>
<input type="radio" name="grupoRadio" ng-value="CNP" ng-model="valor">  Certificado de cobertura con nómina de personal parcial
```

Comment: i don't think you need `ngValue` directive, angular expect that you have in the controller `$scope.CNC = 'something';` - You should just use the simple `value` attribute, and only use `ngValue` when you need to bind a value from the controller

Answer (score 1):

`ng-value` used for variable which is defied in `scope`, if you want to assign some static data you need `value` attribute of `input` like

```
<input type="radio" name="grupoRadio" value="1" ng-model="valor" > Certificado de cobertura sin nómina de personal
 <br>
<input type="radio" name="grupoRadio" value='CNC' ng-model="valor" > Certificado de cobertura con nómina de personal completa
 <br>
<input type="radio" name="grupoRadio" value="CNP" ng-model="valor">  Certificado de cobertura con nómina de personal parcial
```

if you have some variable to bind

```
$scope.data = [{
    {text: 'Certificado de cobertura sin nómina de personal', value: '1'},
    {text: 'Certificado de cobertura con nómina de personal completa', value: 'CNC'},
    {text: 'Certificado de cobertura con nómina de personal parcial', value: 'CNP'}
]

<span ng-repeat="item in data">
    <input type="radio" name="grupoRadio" ng-value="item.value" ng-model="valor" > {{item.text}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings should be wrapped by `'` as you do in normal js files.

like `ng-value="'CND'"`

```
<div>
<input type="radio" name="grupoRadio" ng-value="1" ng-model="valor" > Certificado de cobertura sin nómina de personal
 <br>
<input type="radio" name="grupoRadio" ng-value="'CNC'" ng-model="valor" > Certificado de cobertura con nómina de personal completa
 <br>
<input type="radio" name="grupoRadio" ng-value="'CNP'" ng-model="valor">  Certificado de cobertura con nómina de personal parcial
```

Take a look fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/7r5yvbsj/2/